# css form layout oddity

Tags: css, forms, web

Can someone please tell me why the form at [this location](http://www.sonogenics.co.uk/test/) does not layout as expected? I want the label on the left and the form input on the right. The layout does not display correctly in Chrome 16.0* or Safari 5.1.1 but does display correctly in Firefox 8. There must be something simple I'm missing but I can thinking of it. 
[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I'm using Chrome 16, and Name/Email/etc appear directly to the left of their respective input boxes. I also checked Safari 5 and it looks the same. My Firefox is the only one where it looks bizarre, actually.

Comment: Having no Problems with Chrome 15 on Windows 7. What OS do you run?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to say I'm on OSX 10.7.1. I'll attach a screenshot to illustrate.

Comment: Your screenshot is in which browser?

Comment: It looks just fine to me under OS X 10.7.2 with Safari 5.2.1. Maybe it's a Safari issue. Sorry if this a dumb suggestion, but have you made sure you have cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Completely unrelated but still awesome: Use `id`s on your form elements and have a respective `for=` attribute on each label. It will have an awesome functionality feature that when you click on the labels, the respective form elements will gain focus. The same effect can be achieved if the input is placed inside its own label.

Comment: Strangely enough your screenshot is exactly how my FF8 looks on Windows 7, and Chrome 16/Safari 5 look "correct."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.clearfoats` divs dont have any CSS attached to it. Adding `clear: both` on it solves the problem for me. I'm using Chrome 17 on Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: There's `#clearfloats { clear: both; }` in the CSS, but then `class="clearfloats"` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell because everything is floating left with no clears then if the space is rendered differently in a different browser then it will throw everything off. Your best bet is to put in a `clear:left` after each label/input box combination.

It looks like if add your clearfloats div after each group it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have li in a div. Closed textarea i the opening tag `' />'` and then you're closing it again with `'</textarea>'` and lastly you have `'</a>'` but no opening tag. Fix that first. By the way it's not working in FF on windows as well.